# pagination not working in my category pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pagination

I am getting the error with my pagination when I click on a category in my store. It should be noted that pagination is working correctly on my index page. I am new to rails and do not understand this error. any help would be great, thanks!

NoMethodError in Listings#index

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Listing::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x9178008>

 <br>

   <div class="center">
     <%= will_paginate @posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
   </div>

   <% if user_signed_in? %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add pagination to my category filter in the controller.

```
def index
    if params[:category].blank?
      @listings = Listing.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 16)
    else
      @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
      @listings = Listing.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 16)
    end
  end
```